# ValueAnimator choppy in listview

Tags: android, animation, android-listview

I have a custom view that contains an animation in `onSizeChanged`. Below is the code for the animation:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int xNew, int yNew, int xOld, int yOld){
    super.onSizeChanged(xNew, yNew, xOld, yOld);

    ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofFloat((float)(xNew * percentComplete));//.ofInt(0, (int) (xNew * percentComplete));
    va.setDuration(1000);
    va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            Float value = (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            foregroundView.getLayoutParams().width = value.intValue();
            foregroundView.requestLayout();
        }
    });
    va.start();

}
```

The animation works great when my custom view is **not** in a `ListView` item. However, I have some cases when the custom view is in a `ListView` item, and the animation becomes very choppy. Is `onSizeChanged` the best place to animate the width?